# C++11 Using Iterators for Vectors of Template Parameter Types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, vector

I have a template class which contains a vector of pointers of a type given as a template parameter. I want to be able to use range-based iteration to iterate over a *limited portion* of the vector. My class contains the following functions:

```
template< typename ObjectType >
class ObjectList
{

    ...

public:

    //! Begin iteration over a list of objects
    std::vector<ObjectType*>::iterator begin();

    //! Iterator to one past the end of the list of objects
    std::vector<ObjectType*>::iterator end();

private:

    std::vector<ObjectType*> object_ptrs;
};
```

This fails to compile with the description `Error C2061 syntax error: identifier 'iterator'`. I can't think of any reason why `std::vector<ObjectType>::iterator` should ever not be found, unless `ObjectType` itself cannot be found, but the rest of the class instantiates successfully if I remove the lines which reference `iterator`.

Anyone have an idea what is going on? I'm sure it's possible I'm missing something obvious. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you tell us the compiler you use ? Because mine (gcc 5.3) is pretty explicit about this problem.

Comment: About iterating over a limited portion of a container, it's not currently supported by the standard library. There may be *ranges* coming to the next ([C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) supposedly) standard. There are [libraries](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) you can use though.

Comment: @kebs I'm using msvc, unfortunately. I suppose I should make a habit of trying things in both when I don't understand the error.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I disagree with the duplicate tag, the question here is "why doesn't this compile ?" which is not the same question as the other.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The fact that ranges are not supported in the way that I need is precisely the reason that I am building this class. It seems too small of a reason to bother including another library just for this, and besides, it's always good for me to learn new stuff :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `typename` here, because `std::vector<ObjectType*>` is a dependent type name which depends on the template parameter `ObjectType`.

```
typename std::vector<ObjectType*>::iterator begin();
typename std::vector<ObjectType*>::iterator end();
```

$14.6/2 Name resolution [temp.res]

> A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is
>   dependent on a template-parameter is assumed not to name a type unless
>   the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is qualified
>   by the keyword typename.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the compiler that iterator is a type, as it depends on a template parameter:

```
template< typename ObjectType >
class ObjectList
{
public:

    //! Begin iteration over a list of objects
    typename std::vector<ObjectType*>::iterator begin();

    //! Iterator to one past the end of the list of objects
    typename std::vector<ObjectType*>::iterator end();

private:

    std::vector<ObjectType*> object_ptrs;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Compiler does not know, whenever `iterator` is a type or a static member. You have to add `typename` before the function return type in order to help compiler to disambiguate:

```
typename std::vector<ObjectType*>::iterator begin();
```

Also, new g++ (at least, since 5.3.0) produces more readable error message:

> main.cpp:11:5: error: need `typename` before
>   `std::vector<ObjectType*>::iterator` because
>   `std::vector<ObjectType*>` is a dependent scope
>        `std::vector<ObjectType*>::iterator begin()`